# Method to check for Positive definite matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-mathematics, positive-definite

I think its already been asked , but still i can't figure out a way to do it computationally,

I had to check for positive definiteness of a matrix $A$ of order $n$ by $n$.I know that for any vector $x$ of order $1$ by $n$ , $x^{t}Ax > 0$,

But the problem is i want to implement it while coding a C++ program for Cholesky method in which i need both 1)Symmetric matrix and 2)Positive definite matrix.

How do i approach this situation,if i go for the definition then it can be computationally inefficient as i have to check for each vector $x$.

Any other method which i can use for Positive - definiteness. ?

Any help is great!

Comment: I saw that it can be checked by taking the determinant of sub-square matrices and checking if they all are positive, but that too is little computationally difficult as we have to take each sub square matrix and then again determinant of those!

Comment: Also i could not find a tag related to c++ , eventhough a tag of matlab is there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A matrix $A$ is positive definite if and only if the symmetric matrix $M = A + A^T$ is positive definite.  You should be able to find a program that *attempts* a Cholesky decomposition on $M$.  If it succeeds, then $A$ is positive semidefinite.  If it succeeds and the resulting lower-triangular matrix has only non-zero elements on the diagonal (or a non-square lower-triangular matrix), then $A$ is positive definite.  If the Cholesky decomposition fails, then $A$ is not positive semidefinite (and of course, not positive definite).

**Note:** The above is a standard method for checking whether a matrix is positive definite. While this method is fine in the "general case", it is liable to yield false positives/negatives in the case that $A$ is close to being (or is) singular. See the other answer (and the linked extension) for a more thorough discussion of these "edge cases".

---

About $A + A^T$: note that for any $x$, we have
$$
2(x^TAx) = x^T(Ax) + (Ax)^Tx = x^TAx + x^TA^Tx = x^T(A + A^T)x
$$
clearly, $x^TAx$ will be positive (or non-negative) if and only if $x^T(A + A^T)x$ is positive (or non-negative).

Comment: Oh nice..Can you give some reference to this..

Comment: @BAYMAX sorry, don't really have a good reference off the top of my head.  My guess is that Trefethen and Bau might have something relevant in there, though

Comment: it was nice short answer though!

Comment: @BAYMAX did you mean a reference for $A$ is positive definite if and only if $A + A^T$ is positive definite?  Because that's a quick proof.

Comment: Actually i needed both, How to get the first one?

Comment: See my edit.  Don't have a reference for the Cholesky stuff, though.

Comment: On the contrary, Cholesky's algorithm is not a reliable test for being symmetric positive definite. False positives and false negatives are possible due to the limitations of finite precision arithmetic. Examples can be found in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3095586/307944)

Comment: @CarlChristian Any algorithm is going to run into some amount of trouble with finite precision arithmetic. In any case, what do you recommend instead then?

Comment: @Carl I suppose eigenvalue calculation via the QR method an the like is more robust. Still, the practical question becomes a matter of balancing precision against speed, and there are situations where using the Cholesky algorithm would be appropriate

Comment: @Carl It's not a definitive reference, but I can at least be reassured that [the Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/determine-whether-matrix-is-positive-definite.html) agrees with me.

Comment: I am pointing out that your answer assumes exact arithmetic which is *not* available to the OP who is engaged in actual programming. The fact that Mathworks considers Cholesky's infallible is disturbing, but it does not surprise me.The practical alternative is to compute an $LDL^T$ factorization of $A$ which does not require square roots. This procedure reveals a class of perturbation $\Delta A$ sufficent to ensure that $A+\Delta A$ has only strictly positive eigenvalues.

Comment: @Carl The mathworks site discusses the numerical issue in the "Numerical Considerations" section at the end, where they say that eigenvalue-thresholding is more robust. No one is saying that floating point arithmetic is infallible

Comment: I am sorry, but without a disclaimer, I cannot see how your current text can be read as anything but an endorsement of Cholesky's algorithm as a *practical* test for determining if a matrix is symmetric positive definite or not. It is the choice of the word 
"program" which I associate with computers and finite precision arithmetic to an extent where it is impossible for me to read it in any other way.

Comment: @CarlChristian But it **is** a practical test that works except in pathological cases. For instance, if you generate a random symmetric matrix by independently selecting random entries and apply the Cholesky test, the chances of a false positive/negative are miniscule

Comment: @CarlChristian If it is likely that the matrix is positive *semidefinite*, then of course a more precise method should be used. If the matrix is sufficiently well conditioned, we can categorically rule out examples of the kind that you constructed

Comment: I am not questioning your expertise, but we are not writing for one another, we are writing for an audience with very different background. Exceptions are useful, because they serve as constant reminder that the disaster is just one flop away. An algorithm as simple and common as substitution works nicely, except for those systems for which the growth is exponential. Ironically, the worst systems are also well-conditioned in sense of Skeel.There is much software written by otherwise competent scientists who are not aware of the limitations of their machine. I feel obligated to caution them.

Comment: @Carl I'm not sure what you mean by "sense of Skeel". In any case, I'm convinced; the issue bears mentioning. I've added a disclaimer to my answer accordingly.

Comment: I am very happy that we had this exchange. I find it very difficult to communicated these matters without face to face contact. When I wrote "well conditioned in the sense of Skeel", I meant that Skeel's condition number $cond(T,x) = \| |T| |T^{-1}| |x| \|_\infty/\|x\|_\infty$ was small.

Comment: @Carl Yes, I'm glad we reached a satisfying conclusion. And I didn't know that this condition had a name attached to it, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

There are symmetric positive definite matrices $M$ for which Cholesky's algorithm will fail due to the limitations of floating point arithmetic.

A specific example is given here. Let $u \ll 1$ denote the unit round off error and consider the matrix
$$ M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 + 2u & 1 \\ 1 & 1 - u \end{bmatrix}.$$
This matrix is exactly representable. It is clear that $M$ is symmetric positive definite, for
$$ \text{Tr}(M) = 2 + u > 0$$
and
$$ \text{det}(M) = u - 2u^2 > 0.$$

Now let $\text{fl}(x)$ denote the floating point representation of the real number $x$. Since 
$$1+2u = (1 + u)^2 - u^2$$
we have
$$ 1 < \sqrt{1 + 2 u} < 1 + u < 1 + 2u. $$
It follows that $\text{fl}(\sqrt{1+2u}) = 1$ as there are no floating point numbers in the open interval between $1$ and $1+2u$ and we must pick the option which has the smallest error. After processing the first column of $M$ and performing the linear update of the lower right corner, we are left with
$$ M^{(1)} = \begin{bmatrix} 1  & 1 \\ 1 & - u \end{bmatrix}.$$
The algorithm will now fail because the final pivot is strictly negative.

In general, if Cholesky's algorithm runs to completion, then it produces the *exact* factorization of a matrix $\hat{M} = \hat{L}\hat{L}^T $ which is *close* to $M$. This may very well be enough for your purposes, especially if you can establish that the smallest eigenvalue of $\hat{M}$ is not too small.

Comment: An extended version of this answer which also includes an example of a false positive can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3095586/307944)