# How to deal with underflow issues in high-dimensional entropy calculation?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, covariance, entropy, floating-point

I was not sure if the question makes sense here or should better be placed in a computational/CS forum, but I hope you can give me some insights.

I am working in image processing and use the following formula to compute the entropy of a $d\times N$ matrix that contains $N$ vectorized regions sampled across an image as in [1]. I am using the assumption that the sampled points follow a Gaussian distribution with covariance matrix $\Sigma_d\in \mathbb{R}^{dxd}$ to be able to compute the entropy directly as in [2].

$$H_g(\Sigma_d ) = \log\left((2\pi e)^{\frac{d}{2}}|\Sigma_d|^\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

As the covariance matrix is positive definite symmetric the determinant should be greater than zero.

In practice the problem seems to be that the covariance matrix $\Sigma_d$ is near-singular in many cases and hence $|\Sigma_d|^\frac{1}{2}$ becomes $0$ (due to precision reasons?) and the log goes to $-\inf$. This is problematic as I use the entropies to compute the mutual information in an optimization process.

My idea now was to rewrite the formula as

$$ H_g(\Sigma_d ) = \frac{d}{2}\log2\pi e + \frac{1}{2}\log|\Sigma_d|
$$
and use $|M| = \prod_{i=1}^d \lambda_i$ where $\lambda_i$ are the Eigenvalues of $M \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ and hence $\log|\Sigma_d| = \sum_{i=1}^d \log\lambda_i$ to get

$$
H_g(\Sigma_d ) = \frac{d}{2}\log(2\pi e) + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^d \log \lambda_i 
$$

This seems to be more robust against underflow issues (resulting in $-\inf$) when computing the log of near-zero Eigenvalues.

My **question** now is:

Why is this the case from a mathematical/numerical standpoint? So, why is it less often the case that I get a $-\inf$ result this way? Is there a computational reason, why this way is numerically more robust?

[1] *Russakoff, Daniel B.; Tomasi, Carlo; Rohlfing, Torsten; Maurer, Calvin R. jun.*, [**Image similarity using mutual information of regions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/b97871), Pajdla, Tomáš (ed.) et al., Computer vision – ECCV 2004. 8th European conference on computer vision, Prague, Czech Republic, May 11–14, 2004. Proceedings, Part III. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-21982-X/pbk). Lecture Notes in Computer Science 3023, 596-607 (2004). [ZBL1098.68852](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1098.68852).

[2] *Cover, Thomas M.; Thomas, Joy A.*, Elements of information theory, Wiley Series in Telecommunications. New York: John Wiley & Sons, Inc. xxii, 542 p. (1991). [ZBL0762.94001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0762.94001).

Comment: This is question which is a very good fit for https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/
While the queue is shorter on that forum, there is a very good chance that anyone who is active also monitors the numerical methods tag here.

Comment: I took the liberty of adjusting your tags a bit. Linear-algebra did not apply and was replaced with numerical-linear-algebra. I felt that log was included in entropy and much less important than floating-point. While logarithms are used in your approach, they are not as central to the issues you are facing as the limitations of floating-point arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In numerical work we distinguish between the exact target values and the computed approximations. Frequently, it is impossible to obtain the target value exact as rounding errors accumulate and we are not necessarily able to compensate fully. Your workaround functions perfectly as long as the computed eigenvalues are positive. All IEEE compliant computers will balk at computing the product $ab$ where $a=b=2^{-600}$ because the exact result is $c=2^{-1200}$ which is far outside the representational range of IEEE double precision numbers. The computed result is $\hat{c} = 0$. Computing $\log_2(\hat{c})$ will result in -INF. In contrast, your workaround (applied to $\log_2$) will return the correct result of $-1200$.

You will still experience problems when one of your eigenvalues is computed as a tiny negative number. This is not uncommon even when the exact matrix is symmetric positive definite. This is due to the fact that the smallest eigenvalues are very sensitive to perturbations of the original matrix. Mathematically, we say that they are ill-conditioned. The rounding errors committed when extracting the eigenvalues will push them a little bit and this can be enough to ruin the computed sign when the exact values are sufficiently small. The problem is fundamental and there is very little that you can do about it. When you attempt to compute the logarithm of a strictly negative number an IEEE compliant machine will return NaN (Not A Number) and raise a flag. NaNs will ruin all future calculations as any operation involving at least one NaN will produce another NaN and rightfully so.

An alternative which is less likely to fail dramatically is to compute the determinant differently. Instead of extracting the eigenvalues you compute a QR factorization of a matrix $A$. It takes the form $AP = QR$. Here $P$ is permutation matrix, $Q$ is orthogonal and $R$ is upper triangular with diagonal entries which will always be computed as nonnegative real numbers. Moreover, the diagonal entries will decay monotonically starting in the upper left corner. Technically, this is called "a $QR$ factorization with column pivoting". For the LAPACK implementation see this [link](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node42.html). You have $|\text{det}(A)| = |\text{det}(R)|$ and you can deploy your scheme to compute the determinant of $R$. You will still need to check for the very first zero on the diagonal of $R$. You cannot take advantage of the fact that $A$ is symmetric.

However, and I cannot stress this enough, you are not necessarily getting an accurate result. You are increasing the odds of avoiding a crash and getting a result. That may be good enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. I will certainly look into using the QR factorization. I have also found a paper using the Cholesky decomposition (and adding small values to the diagonal elements of the covariance matrix) to make the computation more stable. I suppose it is a similar idea.

Comment: @NaturalCoder: You are very welcome. I am not sure that replacing $A$ with $A+\alpha I$ is useful for your problem. At least I do not see how I can get information about the determinant of $A$ from the determinant of $A+\alpha I$. There are some situations where shifting the diagonal *is* useful. It would be very interesting for me to browse the paper that you refer to. Would you add a link? Put the hyperlink in soft brackets after, say, the word link which you put inside square brackets and it should render nicely here. This is what I did in my reply.

Comment: I am refering to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.12037). In the section on implementation details when they write about the underflow issue. I have to say I didn't find the exact point of reference the authors mentioned ([27 page59]) which is the Matrix Cookbook to arrive at the given formula either.

Comment: The reference to the specific page of the Matrix Cookbook appears off. Adding a shift to the main diagonal appears legitimate because it is not the value of the determinant which is relevant, rather the location of a optimal point during an optimization point. I doubt that the same value of the shift, i.e., $10^{-6}$ works well in general, but no doubt it worked well for the author's problems.

Comment: Strictly speaking it is possible for Cholesky's algorithm to fail in finite precision arithmetic, see these [examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3095586/307944), but if the smallest eigenvalue of a symmetric positive definite matrix $A$ is large enough, then Cholesky's algorithm runs to completion, browse this [paper](http://www.cs.umu.se/~spock/scans/NoviSad1985.pdf). In other words, if the shift is large enough, but not too large, then the procedure works.

Comment: The QR factorization removes the need to choose a shift, but increases the computational cost. Many people would favor speed over safety, but I am not one of them :)