# The Numerical Issues of Computing The QR-Decomposition Using CholeskyQR

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, orthogonality, cholesky-decomposition

I have an application where I need to compute the QR-decomposition (in fact I only need $R$) of a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ ($m > n$). The matrix has a fixed number of columns, but the number of rows can vary from one run to another. The matrix rows are known one at a time.

I am working within an embedded environment with very restricted memory, so I intend to avoid storing the matrix and work with the rows as they become available. While researching QR algorithms I came across CholeskyQR where the $Q$ and $R$ matrices are computed as
$$ R = Cholesky (A^TA) $$
and then
$$ Q = AR^{-1} $$

I find this method particularly appealing because I can compute $A^TA$ on the fly. But if I understand it correctly, the method is generally avoided due to the ill-conditionning of the Gram matrix $A^TA$ and by extension $R$, which can result in $Q$ not being orthogonal.

I mainly have two questions

1. If I only care about the $R$ matrix, and not intend to use it to solve any linear systems, are there any other numerical difficulties in using CholeskyQR to obtain $R$ or is safe to use.
2. Are there other algorithms that are better suited for my application (computing only $R$ without storing the full matrix $A$)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Given your requirements, you might use Givens rotations QR factorization. Note that you do not need to store them or multiply them together to obtain the orthogonal factor if you do not need it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've definitely considered using either Givens or Householder to reduce new rows as they become available. But they are both slower than just constructing the Gram matrix followed by Cholesky. I'm not sure if the method I mentioned in my post is stable enough for my requirements.

Comment: If the matrix is large enough, then you can accelerate the use of Givens rotations are by accumulating several rotations into single orthogonal transformation and apply this transformation using BLAS3 operations. The matrix needs to be sufficiently wide and you need to process several new rows at once. If the matrix is tiny, then it rarely matters what you do in terms of speed. Cholesky's algorithm can still fail due to rounding errors and this issue is more likely to happen when the matrix is severely ill-conditioned. We need more data about the dimensions, conditioning and your computer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @CarlChristian. I completely neglected the fact that Cholesky might break due to the ill-conditioning of the input matrix. Considering the additional information about the matrix; $A$ is dense and very thin ($n = 5$), the number of rows can be in the dozens or hundreds. I do not yet know how to estimate or put an upper bound on the condition number of a matrix without explicitly computing it using the 2-norm. This is something that I'm currently looking into.

Comment: Extreme examples of the failure of Cholesky's algorithm to determine if a matrix is positive definite or not are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3095586/307944) In the situation that you describe I do not believe that it is possible for you to do better than reduce the first 5 rows to upper triangular form and then use Givens rotations to nullify each successive row. There is no real potential for SIMD operations here, unless you have multiple matrices that are all slowly growing. In this case, you may be able to interleave the data and apply SIMD instructions.

Comment: Batched BLAS is the closest match to a project/library that I know of that may be of use to  you.

Comment: To clarify: Because your matrix is so narrow, there is no blocking potential across the columns and I do not believe that it is possible to gain anything by accumulating multiple Givens rotations into a dense matrix. It might help a bit to add multiple rows before doing the reduction, but now we are down at a level where we have to think about the memory layout and the order of the operations.

Comment: Thank you again @CarlChristian for the very helpful insights. I agree, the more I look into it, the more I find the best course of action is to reduce the first $5 \times 5$ sub-matrix and then nullify the new rows as they become available according to [Updating the QR factorization and the least squares problem](http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/1192/1/qrupdating_12nov08.pdf). I don't have any experience working directly with BLAS. Currently I'm using the Eigen library with full compiler optimization enabled.

Comment: Your are very welcome. When I suggested Batched BLAS (BBLAS, not BLAS itself), it was because it is the only project/library that I am aware of that deals with matrices that are too small to benefit from SIMD operations in the traditional manner, i.e., dense matrix matrix multiplications. BLAS performs well when the matrices are sufficiently large. I think that your current approach is good. You may be able to remove some memory operations if you reduce the new rows in small groups. It may also help a bit if you can read entire rows (5 elements) into 512 bit SIMD registers.

Comment: I'll definitely look into Batched BLAS. I am currently prototyping the design on a Zynq SoC based on ARM Cortex-A9 and a NEON SIMD engine, so I'm definitely prioritizing any method that takes advantage of the SIMD capabilities. My sincere thanks for the continuous help @CarlChristian.